# Next.js - How to build large projects?

Tags: nginx, architecture, next.js

Due to the growth of my project, I faced with question: how to develop large projects on Next.js? What structure should the project have?

For example, I have `Main app` on different paths like `/`, `/main-sub-path`, `/main-sub-path-2/blabla`, etc. Also I have an `Admin panel app` that hosted on `/admin` path. And there can be many such mini-applications, that hosted on certain path and on one domain.

So, how to build such projects? Combine all applications into one huge app (and have one next.js server for the entire application), or divide them into several next.js servers and launch them on different ports by nginx? And what about performance of these approaches?

I would be grateful for your answers!

Comment: Seen a duplicate question but I can't find it anymore. Same response here: you would definitely want to explore how Next.js frameworks and boilerplate are structured. You can check Blitz.js, Next Right Now, Vulcan Next (mine), Bedrock (not open source though and to be published in march this year) and many others. To answer more precisely I prefer to build 1 app per use case, but in the early stages of the project that may be difficult and not very useful until you have a lot of users.